# I have the wrong permission for my data in the volume with wordpress in docker

Tags: docker

I have worked through a tutorial to install wordpress in docker. Unfortunately my data in the volume has the wrong permission and I can't edit it. When I try to edit my file or create a new one, my VSCode says: `Failed to save 'hello.php': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.`

I have two solutions in mind but I am not sure if this is wrong.

**My volume**

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 24 19:33 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 marty marty 4096 Aug 24 18:09 ...
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 28 Jan 8 2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 8 21:32 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 8 21:32 themes
```

**My two approaches**

1. i'm thinking of recursively rewriting the entire volume folder to my user and group `marty`.
2. i add my user `marty` to the group `www-data`. However, i am not sure if the group `www-data` comes from the docker container or from my host in this case.

**Question:** Is there a better solution?

Comment: How are the permissions "wrong"? What does it mean for permissions to be "wrong"? `Is there a better solution?` documentation https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress section "Running as an arbitrary user"

Comment: @KamilCuk When I try to edit my file or create a new one, my VSCode says: `Failed to save 'hello.php': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error means that your user is not able to write in your volume files because they owned by `www-data`. Please try this:

```
sudo chown -R marty volume_foldername (or single files, folders in your volume)
```

Afterwards `marty` will be have access to the `volume_folder` directory.